# Json Parsing: How to fetch "body" data inside "body array" using Gson (or better in other java library or notation supported)?

Tags: java, json, java-8, gson, json-simple

My Rest API is returning the following response, in which only the inner list is required, all data shall be discarded:

```js
{
  "meta": [],
  "links": [],
  "body": [
    {
      "meta": [],
      "links": [],
      "body": {
        "field1": "value1",
        "fieldn": "valuen"
      } // <-----
    },
    {
      "meta": [],
      "links": [],
      "body": {
        "field1": "value1",
        "fieldn": "valuen"
      } // <-----
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way in `Gson` or another other java library to fetch an array of the body or a straightforward way of doing that? Or maybe even using standard of java 8?

Or, should I use a standard iterator as follows:

```java
//Old way to do this
JSONArray BodyArr = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Body");
Iterator<JSONObject> itBody = BodyArr.iterator();
int teller = 0;
while (itBody.hasNext()) {
  JSONObject bodyObj = itBody.next();
  JSONObject body = (JSONObject) bodyObj.get("Body");
}
```

Also in mysql we have way to do that using notation ($.body.body[] etc.). Is there any notational way to fetch the object

Answer (score 1):

I think we have a nicely written article on this.

[Json object iteration](https://www.baeldung.com/jsonobject-iteration)

Comment: Thanks Mubaraka. I can see it is again For each based iteration. I can use it but i am looking for some kind a notational approach if available to avoid looping or some otehr straight forward way. If not found this would be my answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class that represents an object in the array, then you can deserialize the `JSONArray` to an array of that class using `public <T> T fromJson​(JsonElement json, java.lang.Class<T> classOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException` on the `Gson` class:

```java
class BodyItem {
    public String[] meta;
    public String[] links;
    public String field1;
    public String fieldn;
}

public BodyItem[] getBodyItems(final Gson gson, final JsonObject jsonObject) {
    final JsonElement body = jsonObject.get("body");
    return gson.fromJson(body, BodyItem[].class);
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String response = "<your REST API JSON response>";
    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    final JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(response, JsonObject.class);
    final BodyItem[] bodyItems = getBodyItems(gson, jsonObject);
}
```

If you want a more notational way of accessing fields in Gson objects, you can use `JsonObject`'s convenience accessors:

- `JsonArray getAsJsonArray​(java.lang.String memberName)`
- `JsonObject getAsJsonObject​(java.lang.String memberName)`
- `JsonPrimitive getAsJsonPrimitive(java.lang.String memberName)`

And then with a `JsonArray`, you can iterate with `for (final JsonElement element : jsonArray)` or `.forEach`, and you can get `JsonElement`s with the `JsonElement get(int i)` accessor.

So, say you had your original `JsonObject` response and wanted to get the value of `body.field1` in the second element of the `body` list, you might do:

```java
String value = jsonObject
    .getAsJsonArray("body")
    .get(1)
    .getAsJsonObject()
    .getAsJsonObject("body")
    .getAsJsonObject("field1");
```